# IF ELSE in function to increase variable

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to use function with if..else used as leveling system?

I can't get it to work. I want to press a button to increase the `var str`, if you have enough stp"stat points"

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huagrxv7/)

JS Code

```
var str = 0;
var stp = 10;

if (localStorage.stp) stp = localStorage.getItem('stp');
document.getElementById("stp").innerHTML = stp;

if (localStorage.str) str = localStorage.getItem('str');
document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = str;

function strUpg(number){
    if(stp >= 1){
        str = parseInt(str) + 1;
        stp = parseInt(stp) - 1;
        document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = str;
        localStorage.setItem('str', str);
        document.getElementById("stp").innerHTML = stp;
        localStorage.setItem('stp', stp);
    }else if{
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to do nothing, you don't need `else`.

Comment: `else if` needs to be followed by another condition. If there's no condition, just use `else`, not `else if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, you have to remove the `if` in `else if`

ex.

```
function strUpg(number){
    if(stp >= 1){
        str = parseInt(str) + 1;
        stp = parseInt(stp) - 1;
        document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = str;
        localStorage.setItem('str', str);
        document.getElementById("stp").innerHTML = stp;
        localStorage.setItem('stp', stp);
    }else{ //remove the if
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/huagrxv7/2/) for a working example of how to get rid of this issue with this algorithm :

**HTML**

```
<p>Stat points: <span id="stp">10</span></p>
<p>Str: <span id="str">0</span></p>
<p><button onClick="strUpg(1)">Level Str</button></p>
```

**JavaScript plain**

```
var str = 0;
var stp = 10;

if (localStorage.stp) stp = localStorage.getItem('stp');
document.getElementById("stp").innerHTML = stp;

if (localStorage.str) str = localStorage.getItem('str');
document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = str;

function strUpg(number){
    if(stp > 0) {
        stp--;
        str++;
        document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = str;
        document.getElementById("stp").innerHTML = stp;
    }
    else {
        alert("No more stat points available");   
    }
}
```

I simplifyied the algorithm so the algorithm is not that complicated to understand, I increase the value of `str` only if there is enough of `stp` by checking `if (stp > 0)`, else an alert is displayed but you can do something else with it.

I guess others stats work the same, stamina, etc...